# Can symmetrize by used with the multires modifier?

Tags: modifiers, mirror, sculpting

I was sculpting a hand on a character with a multires modifier, and I hid the rest of the character (including the other hand). Because the other hand was hidden it didn't get effected by the sculpting symmetry. So my question is, can the sculpting that I did on that hand somehow be mirrored to the other hand while still keeping the multires modifier? Something similar to the `Symmetrize` feature of Dyntpo?

Comment: Did you try the edit-mode symmetrize tool?

Comment: @ideasman42 It's a little finicky and it left some artifacts, but after a few tweaks everything was back on track. Thanks!

Comment: How is it finicky?

Comment: @ideasman42 In a few places it reverses the stroke (i.e. an indent becomes an outdent, a crease becomes a mound) But oddly, not all the strokes get reversed, just a few.

Comment: That's not **finicky**, Its a serious bug in the Symmetrize tool which consistently gave incorrect results, committed fix https://developer.blender.org/rB66043cc6c1911c9b8af971fb26916ed8363549ce - please report bugs to our tracker in future.

Comment: @ideasman42 I just tested it, works great! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the edit-mode Symmetrize tool.

> EditMode -> Mesh (Menu) -> Symmetrize

---

Note, there was a bug with Multi-res modifier which is now fixed in daily builds and will be included in the 2.77 release ([commit](https://developer.blender.org/rB66043cc6c1911c9b8af971fb26916ed8363549ce)).

Comment: Would I be correct in assuming that this no longer works, as of 2.90, due to https://developer.blender.org/T73317? I tried to use "Symmetrize" to fix distortion that came from sculpting at a lower level, and instead I just got even worse distortion.

Comment: @WillChen Just used it with 2.92 and it works fine