# How do I get rid of the tear in the middle of my object after using the mirror modifier?

Tags: modifiers, sculpting, mirror, object-mode

I'm sorry if this question has already been asked, but I was following a tutorial and after sculpting, I reapplied the mirror modifier but my mesh looks like this: [image]

Is there is any way to fix this without applying or deleting the mirror modifier.
Thank you, a blender novice

Comment: it looks like you can't use both Multires and Mirror, so maybe delete the Mirror and if you want to mirror, go in Edit mode and go in the bottom menu > Mesh > Symmetrize, it will symmetrize your object with the Multires sculpting

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48711/can-symmetrize-by-used-with-the-multires-modifier

Answer (score 1):

Put the mirror modifier before the multires. Keep clipping on, but make sure all the vertices at the middle are snapped over to center line.

Comment: I tried but it said "Cannot move above modifier requiring original data"

Comment: Can you try to delete multires modifier and add it back after mirror